# If $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} 2^{a_i} 3^i$ is divisible by $2^m - 3^k$, then the quotient is $1$ or $2$ (Existence of cycles in the Collatz-problem)

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Given any two positive integers $m,k$ and a sequence of numbers $a_0, a_1,...,a_{k-1}$ such that $m>a_0>a_1...>a_{k-1}\ge0$,

then $$S=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{2^{a_i}3^i}}{2^m-3^k}\in \mathbb{N} \implies  S=1,2$$

Any idea how to solve this? I quickly wrote up a python script and its true for $m\le20$. Pretty sure this isn't within my level of math but any help or points of attack could be useful

I think this is loosely related to the Collatz conjecture because it involves powers of 3 and 2

Comment: Very odd problem. Where did you get it? I took the reference to collatz out of the title since that probably mislead people, and anyway as you say it seems only loosely related on first glance.

Comment: @6005: no, exactly this is part of the "do cycles exist?" question in the Collatz-problem. One should also say that $m$ and $k$ should be so that  $2^m>3^k$ and more precisely that $2^m>3^k>2^{m-1}$, because if  $2^m<3^k<2^{m+1}$ then there are three more solutions aside rotations in the $a_k$. See an occurence of this formula for instance in my small treatize on the generalization to $3x+r$ at http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_3x_r.pdf where I use $S$ for $m$ and $N$ for $k$ and $A_k$ instead of $a_k$ (and the $a_k$ are the partial sums ofthe sequence of $A_k$)

Comment: ... it is formula (3) in my text.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks for detailing the connection.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms $m \geq k$ as when applying $3n+1$ it is always necessary to apply $n/2$ at least once. Hence $m$ must be at least equal to $k$.

Comment: @Roskiller - if $m \lt k$ then you can consider the negative numbers instead of numbers from $\mathbb N$

Comment: @GottfriedHelms When referring to the collatz conjecture, surely we can only refer to the natural numbers?

Comment: @Roskiller - sure. But to study the basic structure of the problem it is meaningful to generalize to negative numbers as well. As well as to compare with $5x+1$, $7x+1$ and so on problems: to perhaps see what's the special of $3x+1$ to have just one final cycle for all (positive) numbers.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I was simply referring to your statement  that $2^m>3^k$.

Comment: @Roskiller - hmm, I think, I've lost you now. Possibly all our conversation has been mutual misunderstanding? Perhaps, if it is important why not form a new question from it?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms no no, it is of little importance, I just noticed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the question of existence of cycles in the Collatz-problem, and is still open. There are partial solutions, for instance if the sequence of the $a_k$ is $[0,1,2,3,...,N-1$ then we have the "1-cycle" problem for which R. Steiner showed 1976 that there is only one positive integer soultion for the quotient, namely $1$.

The formula occurs in the following way; I use different letters here: $N$ for your $k$ and $S$ for your $m$.

Write the "Syracuse"-notation of the Collatz-problem in odd positive numbers $a$ and $b$ $$a_{k+1} = {3a_k+1 \over 2^{A_k}} \qquad \qquad \text{where }  A_k =v_2(3a_k+1) \tag 1$$
Put this as functional notation $$ a_2=T(a_1;[A_1]) \tag 2$$ and the $N$-fold iteration with the sum $S$ of the $A_k$ then a general transformation can be written as
$$ a_{N+1} = T(a_1;[A_1,A_2,A_3,...,A_N]) \tag 3$$ with the restriction that all $A_k>0$ then the full transformation is expanded
$$ a_{N+1} = {3^N \over 2^S} a_1 + { 3^{N-1} + 3^{N-2}2^{A_1}+ 3^{N-3}2^{A_1+A_2} + ... + 2^{A_1+A_2+...+A_{N-1}} \over 2^S} \tag {4.1}$$
or, introducing a short notation for the long numerator
$$a_{N+1}= {3^N \over 2^S} a_1 + {Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])\over 2^S} \tag {4.2}$$
The the question of the existence of a cycle $a_{N+1}=a_1$ occurs as diophantine quation
$$a_1= {3^N \over 2^S} a_1 + {Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N])\over 2^S} \\
 a_1 (2^S-3^N) = Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N]) \\
 a_1  = {Q([A_1,A_2,...,A_N]) \over 2^S-3^N} \\  \tag 5
$$
for which a solution is sought for a positive odd integer $a_1$ (which is the "quotient" in your question) given a vector of exponents $[A_1,...,A_N]$. Current knowledge is that there is only one such solution which is $1 = T(1;[2])= T(1;[2,2])=...= T(1;[2,2,...,2])$ which is called the "trivial cycle".
To have a positive solution in $a_1$ we must have $2^S>3^N$ ; for the case $2^S<3^N$ there are $3$ further solution for negative odd $a_1$ (three cycles exist in the negative numbers).  See more on this for instnace at [this link](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_3x_r.pdf)

But that question in full generality is still open.

---

The non-excistence of further positive quotients ($a_1$ in the odd positive numbers) is only known for a ***certain structure*** of the exponents-vector, namely of the form $E_{N,s}=[1,1,1,...,1,A_N]$ . Here  $A_N>1$ is such that $S=N-1+A_N$ and $2^S>3^N$ . With this restricion on the exponents there is no positive integer solution for $a_1$ (proof of R. Steiner of non-existence of 1-cycles) and subsequently no solution for $m$-cycles up to $m=72$ . $m$-cycles are defined by $m$ concatenations of that $E$-type vectors of different lengthes and/or trailing $A_N$. The proof were done by J. Simons/B.d.Weger in the years from 2000 to 2008 .

---

***Update:*** A concise and nice remark about your quotient can be seen at [Terence Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/25/the-collatz-conjecture-littlewood-offord-theory-and-powers-of-2-and-3/) , look there for the paragraph containing the name "Sontacchi" and conjecture 3.